# Using indexes in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Strange thing happens. Can anyone please explain.
I have a table.

```
CREATE TABLE "country_ip" (
  "begin_ip" varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  "end_ip" varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  "begin_ip_long" int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  "end_ip_long" int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  "id" char(2) NOT NULL,
  "label" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  KEY "begin_ip_long" ("begin_ip_long","end_ip_long"),
  KEY "end_ip_long" ("end_ip_long")
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

There are about 150 000 records.
next queries have huge time difference

```
0.06329400 | SELECT * FROM `country_ip` WHERE '1405662435' BETWEEN `begin_ip_long` AND `end_ip_long` LIMIT 1
0.06214600 | SELECT * FROM `country_ip` USE INDEX (begin_ip_long, end_ip_long) WHERE 1405662435 BETWEEN `begin_ip_long` AND `end_ip_long` LIMIT 1
0.00008400 | SELECT * FROM `country_ip` USE INDEX (end_ip_long) WHERE 1405662435 BETWEEN `begin_ip_long` AND `end_ip_long` LIMIT 1
```

Can anyone explain why does it happens? I mean why only **USE INDEX (end_ip_long)** helps while using **USE INDEX (begin_ip_long)** or **USE INDEX (begin_ip_long, end_ip_long)**  has no effect. Thanks.

Comment: `Can anyone please explain`? Interestingly MySQL itself can `EXPLAIN` it best :)

Comment: You need an R-Tree (spatial) index.

Comment: Looks like InnoDB does not support Spatial indexes. Anyway it does not explain anything

Comment: Spatial indexes have been supported in InnoDB since 5.0.16; @Quassnoi gives a good explanation in his blog article, [Banning IP’s](http://explainextended.com/2009/04/04/banning-ips/).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because index `(end_ip_long)` is smaller then `(begin_ip_long, end_ip_long)` and it fits in memory and one column is selective enough. While bigger index may require to read from disk.

Comment: No. Because (begin_ip_long) sepatately works fast  0.00007600 | SELECT * FROM `country_ip` USE INDEX (begin_ip_long) WHERE  `begin_ip_long` <= 1405662435 LIMIT 1

Comment: This does not mean anything. alexius esplained why MySQL chooses end_ip_long, and I think he's right. You can disagree with MySQL's optimizer, but it will still follow its rules. Anyway, when asking questions like this, you should provide EXPLAIN's output. SELECT's time doesn't mean much, and means nothing with LIMIT 1.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can get the single-column (END_IP_LONG) index to work fast, why not just index & search on one column?

I'd probably use BEGIN_IP_LONG and search for the first record where specified IP was >= country.BEGIN_IP_LONG, order them by IP descending, limit 1. That should retrieve the "floor" entry, all you need to do then is check the specified IP is not beyond the END_IP_LONG of that country.

This will accomplish the lookup correctly, using only a single-column index. (All of this assumes ranges do not overlap, which I assume is true given your stated structures.)

---

As others suggested, investigating MySQL's plan (and perhaps rebuilding statistics) would be worthwhile -- but technically, non-overlapping range lookups should technically be possible using an index on only a single bound.